# Dealing with Limit Superior and Limit Inferior?

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Let $X_n =\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ find the $\limsup X_n$ and $\liminf X_n$. Proof.

Can someone help me create a proof for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing which can be easily observed that $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is a convergent sequence with 0 as its limit. So
$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0$.
Next, by definition 
$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}y_k$, where
$y_k=\sup\{x_n:n\geq k\}$ and $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}z_k$, where $z_k=\inf\{x_n:n\geq k\}$. Now note that both limits of $y_k$ and $z_k$ are 0. Hence 
$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0$.

Comment: You guys make it sound easier than what it appears to be. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Think.Does $x_n$ converge? if it does ,then $\limsup x_n= \liminf x_n$.

Answer (score 2):

We have 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup X_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0,$$
because $X_n \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$
and the following,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \inf X_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} -\frac{1}{n} = 0$$
Because $X_n \geq -\frac{1}{n}$, for all $n \geq 1$.
So $X_n$ converges to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.